# How do I pull only one category from custom post type in a template?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to create a template for a custom post type and only pull one category from that post type called "commissioned." The code below pulls all the posts from the custom post type for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Portfolio Masonry Commissioned
 *
 * @package Ridge
 * @since 1.0
 */

get_header();

?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area middle portfolio">
        <main id="main" class="site-main " role="main">

            <?php

            // Don't show the description for the front page
            if( is_page() ) {

                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <div id="portfolio-content">
                        <header class="entry-header">
                            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                        </header>
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>

                <?php endwhile;
            } // if

            /**
             * Set up the skills and projects
             *
             * @see inc/template-tags.php
             */

            // Get the projects WP_Query object
            $args = array(  
                'post_type' => 'project',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => -1, 
                'orderby' => 'date', 
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'cat' => 'commissioned',
            );

            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

            ?>

            <div id="projects" class="masonry">
                <div class="thumbs clearfix">
                    <?php  while ( $loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

                        global $ttrust_config;

                        // Get the skills for each project for the .js data attribute
                        $skills = ridge_get_tax( $post );

                        get_template_part( 'content', 'project-small-masonry' ); ?>

                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

                </div><!-- .thumbs -->
            </div><!-- #projects -->

        </main><!-- .site-main -->
    </div><!-- .content-area -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Update: This is how the Projects CPT is set up.

```
    public function project_init() {

    // Define the settings
    $settings = array(
        'labels'             => array(
            'name'               => __( 'Projects', $this->textdomain ),
            'singular_name'      => __( 'Project', $this->textdomain ),
            'add_new'            => __( 'Add New', $this->textdomain ),
            'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Project', $this->textdomain ),
            'edit'               => __( 'Edit', $this->textdomain ),
            'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Project', $this->textdomain ),
            'new_item'           => __( 'New Project', $this->textdomain ),
            'view'               => __( 'View Project', $this->textdomain ),
            'view_item'          => __( 'View Project', $this->textdomain ),
            'search_items'       => __( 'Search Projects', $this->textdomain ),
            'not_found'          => __( 'No projects found', $this->textdomain ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No projects found in Trash', $this->textdomain ),
            'parent'             => __( 'Parent Project', $this->textdomain ),
        ),
        'public'                 =>true,
        'publicly_queryable'     => true,
        'show_ui'                => true,
        'query_var'              => true,
        'capability_type'        => 'post',
        'hierarchical'           => false,
        'menu_position'          => null,
        'menu_icon'              => get_template_directory_uri(). '/img/blue-folder-stand.png',
        'taxonomies'             => array( 'skills' ),
        'supports'               => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'excerpt' ),
        'rewrite'                => array(
            'slug' => 'project'
        )
    ); // End $settings
```

Update: Got it working!

```
            $args = array(  
            'post_type' => 'project',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1, 
            'orderby' => 'date', 
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array (
                    'taxonomy' => 'skill',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => 'commissioned'
                )
            )
        );
```

Comment: Custom post type, use taxonomy in the query instead of cat? Depends how your CPT is setup

Comment: @DanielVickers It seems the CPT is set up to use taxonomies. I edited the post to include the code. I tried replacing `cat` with `taxonomy` but the page is still pulling all posts from `projects`.

Comment: No problem glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `'category_name' => 'commissioned'` to the `$args` array (instead of `cat => ...`)

Comment: I don't have to use `tax_query` since this is a CPT?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working!

Here's how I set up my arguments.

```
            $args = array(  
            'post_type' => 'project',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1, 
            'orderby' => 'date', 
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array (
                    'taxonomy' => 'skill',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => 'commissioned'
                )
            )
        );
```